# Search button with 'lens' icon on the exposed view's filter - Drupal 7

Tags: forms, views

I can't figure out how to make a search button on the view's exposed (as a block) search filter to be styled similarly as in Drupal standard search form, with a 'lens' icon. The examples for hook_form_alter() I found using:

```
$form['submit']['#type'] = 'image_button';
$form['submit']['#src'] = base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/images/search-button.png';
```

-don't seem to work correctly, as image on the button just doubles (png file includes both 'active' and 'inactive' images of lens). Could there be a straightforward way for the search button 'lens' styling, not including CSS/templates modifications?

Comment: If you try autocomplete for your exposed filter field, autocomplete throbber will take place. But expose filter should be in your field list if you want to use that..

Comment: It seems this already [was asked and answered on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2920076/2389310) - could you tell us why generic way is not for you?

Comment: you can simply do it by using css. No need to make it more complicated by using hook_form_alter().

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, hadn't thought about autocomplete throbber, this may be handy in my case, maybe avoiding a search button altogether, although it's not a common practice.

Comment: Molot and Arun, I thought there may be a "Drupal's way" of making a search button easily configurable in PHP code. Drupal itself is using such search button at "localhost/search" out-of-the-box, so I thought it might be a matter of settings manageable in PHP or using CSS classes. I didn't want to change CSS directly if there is a configurable way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is good. The only "problem" is that your lens image is "sprites" image - designed to be shown only partially, depending on the state of your button. There is no standard for this, so Drupal does not support this. You ave two options there:

1. Cut your image, leave only the part you need.
2. Use CSS to implement sprite style your image was created for.